# Crash With DllImport C#

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, marshalling, dllimport

Gang,

I'm using a third-party API written in (what looks like) MFC C++.  My application is a WinForms app in C#.  The API's company has a C# demo application, and I used their code verbatim.  The relevant code looks like this...

API's C++ Function:

```
int PASCAL CppFunction(BYTE *pbAdapterID, BYTE *pbTargetID, char *pcVendor, char *pcProduct, char *pcRelease, int iMessageBox)
{
    // The function definition is all I can see in the API's documentation
}
```

The DllImport Statement:

```
[DllImport("api.dll")]
extern public static int CppFunction(ref byte pbAdapter, ref byte pbTargetID, string pcVendor, string pcProduct, string pcRelease, int iMessageBox);
```

My C# Logic:

```
public void CallCppFunction()
{
    try
    {
        int result = 0;
        string strVendorBuffer = string.Empty;
        string strProductBuffer = string.Empty;
        string strReleaseBuffer = string.Empty;
        string strSerial = string.Empty;
        byte bAdapt = 0;
        byte bTarg = 0;

        result = CppFunction(ref bAdapt, ref bTarg, strVendorBuffer, strProductBuffer, strReleaseBuffer, 0);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

This is the code as it exists in their C# sample.  When run, it crashes with a "FatalExecutionEngineError" even in a try/catch.

[image]

I don't know PInvoke very well, but don't those variables have to be marshaled as an unmanaged type?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am pretty sure I know the answer but you need to tell me what `CppFunction` is supposed to do first.

Comment: It's a guess. It's probably due to your string handling (you don't specify how you marshal them, use `[MarshalAs]`). If the string parameters are output, you should use `StringBuilder` instead of `string` (with some preallocated storage)

Comment: Without any knowledge of what the interface is nobody can say. The C++ function prototype does not define the interface. The `ref byte` is almost certainly wrong. But what should it be? How can we possibly know with the information presented? We could guess, but do you really go through life writing code by guesswork?

Comment: You may not need to use dllImport.  You may just need to add dll as a reference and add appropriate 'using' statements at top of module.

Comment: @jdweng Really. You think this is a managed DLL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am taking a wild guess here, but I am pretty sure it will be the right answer

Lets take a look to the function definition:

```
int PASCAL CppFunction(
    BYTE *pbAdapterID, 
    BYTE *pbTargetID, 
    char *pcVendor, 
    char *pcProduct, 
    char *pcRelease, 
    int iMessageBox);
```

And the corresponding DllImport declaration:

```
[DllImport("api.dll")]
extern public static int CppFunction(
    ref byte pbAdapter, 
    ref byte pbTargetID, 
    string pcVendor, 
    string pcProduct, 
    string pcRelease,
    int iMessageBox);
```

There are a lot of parameters there, some of them caught my attention:

```
    char *pcVendor, 
    char *pcProduct, 
    char *pcRelease,
```

They are not passed by reference, are they being modified by the library?

Note: That why I asked you to give details about the function.

I that's the case, you cannot marshal strings because the datatype string is immutable, you must use the `StringBuilder` class, just make sure the `StringBuilder`has enough [Capacity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.capacity(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
int result = 0;
StringBuilder strVendorBuffer = new StringBuilder(1024); // up to 1024 chars
StringBuilder strProductBuffer = new StringBuilder(1024); // up to 1024 chars
StringBuilder strReleaseBuffer = new StringBuilder(1024); // up to 1024 chars
StringBuilder strSerial = string.Empty;
byte bAdapt = 0;
byte bTarg = 0;

result = CppFunction(ref bAdapt, ref bTarg, strVendorBuffer, strProductBuffer, strReleaseBuffer, 0);
```

Comment: PASCAL is the same as stdcall, which is pinvoke's default calling convention

Comment: Dont guess. That's the reason asker is stuff. Too much guesswork. The ref byte args are surely wrong. Makes no sense to guess at buffer size too. That won't end well. More plausible that strings are in params. Guessing is really bad advice.

Comment: Sorry someone gave you the down vote.  Unfortunately, what I posted is what I got from the vendor, so we sort of have to guess.  However, I tried replacing the strings with StringBuilders and it worked.  Thanks!!!